# Rectangular graphs in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Whenever I draw a plot using `pgfplots`, the result is always a square grid.  That's generally fine, but in the interest of saving space, something I'd like to be able to make a rectangular plot.

Here's a little plot I made to [demonstrate Euler's identity on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242825/explain-why-ei-pi-1-to-an-8th-grader/1293700#1293700)

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-2,
xmax=2,
ymin=-1,
ymax=1,
axis lines = middle,
disabledatascaling,
axis equal
]
    \addplot[ultra thick, red, ->] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0)};
    \addplot[ultra thick, purple, ->] coordinates {(0,0) (-1,0)};
    \draw [thick, blue] (axis cs:0.3,0) arc [radius=0.3,start angle=0,end angle=180];

    \node[blue] at (axis cs:0.1,0.2) [anchor=south west] {$\pi$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following image:

[image]

Notice that even though I specified `ymin=-1` and `ymax=1`, that the y-axis actually goes past that to produce a square(ish) plot.  What could I do to get the y-axis to *really* go from `-1` to `1`, while keeping the `axis equal` -- i.e. how can I make a rectangular plot that crops out some of the unused space here?

Comment: Replace `axis equal` by `axis equal image`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`axis equal` specifically keeps the unit length ratios equal *as well as* the dimensions of the plot.  So it will override the `xmin`, `xmax`, etc.

`axis equal image` only keeps the unit length ratios equal so you can use it to accomplish your goal.

You can also use `unit vector ratio=1 1` to accomplish the same task.  From Heiko's answer, you can see that you may need to set the compatibility mode to 1.11 or later so that the blue arc renders correctly.

Using either of the above methods will scale the dimensions of your plot without scaling your unit vectors producing a plot that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think, `unit vector ratio` is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-2,
  xmax=2,
  ymin=-1,
  ymax=1,
  axis lines = middle,
  unit vector ratio=1 2,
]
    \addplot[ultra thick, red, ->] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0)};
    \addplot[ultra thick, purple, ->] coordinates {(0,0) (-1,0)};
    \draw [thick, blue] (axis cs:0.3,0) arc [radius=0.3,start angle=0,end
    angle=180];

    \node[blue] at (axis cs:0.1,0.2) [anchor=south west] {$\pi$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: When I try this the blue arc disappears.

Comment: This is fixed by `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}`. Without such a statement, package `pgfplots` uses a backwards compatibility mode with missing features.

Comment: I assume if `compat=1.12` fails that means I need to update my LaTeX distribution.

Comment: @A.Ellett It works for `compat=1.11` and `compat=1.12` with `pgfplots` v1.12. `compat=1.10` failed.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek No, I wanted to keep the relative unit lengths the same.  Paul Gessler gave the answer in the comments above.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bye_World I thought, you wanted the same axis lengths.

Comment: No worries -- I still learned something new: I had never used the `unit vector ratio` option before. :)