# Scale axis to be 1:1 scale in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, scaling, axis

I am trying to draw a plot as following:

[image: What I have]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
            axis lines=center,
            width=25cm,
            height=10cm,
            xmin=0,
            ymin=0,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
            ytick={0,5,10},
            clip=false,
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            grid style=dashed,
            %%%%%%% FIRST ATTEMPT
            %axis equal image,
            %%%%%%% SECOND ATTEMPT
            %x=.5cm,
            %y=.5cm,
            %%%%%%% THIRD ATTEMPT
            %width=24cm,
            %height=10cm,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)(5,5)(8,10)(24,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Since there are less "points?" on `y`-axis than `x`-axis, the graph has a rectangular grid. **I would like to draw the plot with square grids** i.e. something like:

[image: What I want]

I have tried several ways from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246455/152550) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454147/152550) with no success. The attempts are commented on the code.

How can we achieve the desired result? What is the formula for scaling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `unit vector ratio*={5 1 1}`. Note this overwrites `height=10cm`.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
            axis lines=center,
            width=25cm,
            height=10cm,
            unit vector ratio*={5 1 1},  % <<< added
            xmin=0,
            ymin=0,
            xtick={0,1,...,24},
            ytick={0,5,10},
            clip=false,
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            grid style=dashed,
            %%%%%%% FIRST ATTEMPT
            %axis equal image,
            %%%%%%% SECOND ATTEMPT
            %x=.5cm,
            %y=.5cm,
            %%%%%%% THIRD ATTEMPT
            %width=24cm,
            %height=10cm,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0)(5,5)(8,10)(24,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But why the formula `{5 1}`? I mean I don't know why that works; From the PGFPLOTS manual, "Thus, a three dimensional axis with `unit vector ratio=1 2 4` will have an `x` unit which is `1/4` the length of the `z` unit, and a `y` unit which is `2/4` the length of the `z` unit" (p. 302). In our case it is traduced as "The `x` unit will be `5/1` times the length of `y` unit", but why `5`?

Comment: Because every square grid is expected to occupy 1 `x` unit and 5 `y` units.